# C# Забивается оперативная память

Tags: c#, wpf

Я загружаю изображения 240 штук в `ListBox`. 
Но у меня этот процесс отнимает 1600 мб оперативной памяти и я никак не могу освободить эту память. Другие программы, как к примеру Nvidia Geforce Experience показывает все картинки и оперативную память больше 10-15 мб не занимает

Каким образом можно реализовать показ картинок в папке?

Разметка Xaml

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox_Screenshots"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
         ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListBoxItem_Style}"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
         Margin="70,10,70,45" Background="#4DFFFFFF" BorderThickness="2,1"
         SelectionMode="Extended" BorderBrush="#FF21AFE4"
         SelectionChanged="ListBox_Screenshots_SelectionChanged"
         MouseDoubleClick="ListBox_Screenshots_MouseDoubleClick">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel ItemHeight="240" ItemWidth="390"
                       Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Viewbox>
                    <Image>
                        <Image.Source>
                            <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding imgSource}"
                                         CacheOption="OnLoad"/>
                        </Image.Source>
                        <Image.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2" 
                                              BlurRadius="50"
                                              Color="#FF00249C"/>
                        </Image.Effect>
                    </Image>
                </Viewbox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Логика C#

```
//Загружаем все изображения
private void Screenshots_LoadAll()
{
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
                + @"\GTA San Andreas User Files\SAMP\screens";

    var dirs = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                        .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".png") || s.EndsWith(".jpg"));
    foreach (string dir in dirs)
    {
        ListBox_Screenshots.Items.Add(new ImageScreen() { imgSource = dir });
    }
    //Запускаем функцию на ожидание создания или удаления файлов
    Screenshots_StartWatch(path);
}

//Смотрим на создание или удаления файла
private void Screenshots_StartWatch(string path)
{
    FileSystemWatcher watch = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watch.Path = path;
    watch.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(Screenshots_OnCreated);
    watch.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(Screenshots_OnDeleted);
    watch.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    bIsScreenshotsWatching = true;
}


public class ImageScreen :IDisposable
{
    public string imgSource { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        imgSource = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Не в курсе что это

Comment: Я вроде старался и все лишнее убрал. Здесь только Lisbox и код, который добавляет картинки в этот ListBox

Comment: Именно. Зачем лишнее?

Comment: Рискну предположить, что у Вас картинки загружаются целиком, не думаю что Вам нужно показывать 240 картинок в их оригинальном разрешении одновременно. Попробуйте сделать класс картинки который будет хранить путь к изображению и его миниатюру как bitmap.

Comment: виртуализация включена?

Comment: Ничего вроде не включено. Используется привязка <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding imgSource}"> на класс public class ImageScreen :IDisposable
    {
        public string imgSource { get; set; }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            imgSource = null;
        }
    }

Comment: Все таки надо делать в цикле миниатюры и их добавлять в коллекцию для отображения, точнее сделать класс миниатюр со свойствами: свойство типа bitmap для миниатюры и второе свойство полный путь к оригиналу изображения. Если пользователь кликнул по миниатюре, вы всегда сможете подгрузить нужный оригинал.

Comment: @eblomyac: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD не считаю, что совет из разряда "Я бы копал в этом направлении" является однозначным ответом.

Comment: @eblomyac: Не доверяете вы вашей телепатии :)

Answer (score 11):

Для того чтобы не заморачиваться с созданием миниатюр, сначала рекомендую попробовать воспользоваться штатными средствами WPF.

Класс `BitmapImage` имеет ряд свойств предназначенных для этого, в частности  `DecodePixelWidth` и `DecodePixelHeight`

Например, добавление одной строчки:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel ItemHeight="240"
                       ItemWidth="240"
                       Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image>
                <Image.Source>
                    <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding}"
                                 CacheOption="OnLoad"
                                 DecodePixelHeight="240"/> <!--Обратите внимание на эту строку-->
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Позволило снизить потребление ОЗУ на стандартных обоинах Windows 7 с ~440 до ~95 МБ, причем приложение вообще без картинок занимает ~65 МБ.

До: [image: До]

После: [image: После]

Comment: А что, очень изящно!

Comment: Просто удивительно! Этой строчки кода и не хватало. 
Проводник windows 501 шт изображений занимает при прокрутки и загрузке всех - 167 мб памяти,
Моя программа, естественно все сперва подгружает и занимает 217 мб памяти
Огромное спасибо за совет.. Идеально подошло
Теперь осталось подгружать лишь те, что помещаются в окно, это где-то 6 изображений