# Покадровая анимация png

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть ~100 файлов `png` нужно их как бы анимировать, весят они от 8кб до 4мб.

Но как то через чур всё тормознуто выходит.

Можно ли тут что то оптимизировать или сделать более правильно ?

```
    int counter = 0;
    DispatcherTimer dT = new DispatcherTimer();

    public Png()
    {
       InitializeComponent();

       dT.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 25);
       dT.Tick += new EventHandler(dT_Tick);
       dT.Start();
    }

    void dT_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\" + counter + ".png"));
       imageKonteiner.Source = image;
       counter++;

       if (counter == 100)
       {
         dT.Stop();
       }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD** - Пробовал и так заранее в память запихать, вышло тоже не очень(, память процесса подпрыгивает до 4гб :

```
    int counter = 0;
    DispatcherTimer dT = new DispatcherTimer();
    private BitmapImage[] images;

    public Png()
    {
       InitializeComponent();

       images = new BitmapImage[100];

       for(int i = 0 ; i < images.Length; i++)
       {
          images[i] = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\" + i + ".png"));
       }

       dT.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 25);
       dT.Tick += new EventHandler(dT_Tick);
       dT.Start();
    }



   void dT_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      imageKonteiner.Source = images[counter];
      counter++;

      if (counter == 100)
      {
        dT.Stop();
      }
   }
```

Comment: заранее их все в память загрузить нельзя?

Comment: @tym32167 я пробовал, правда с другой папкой, там ~800 файлов и память процесса переваливала за 4гб, хотя файлов там было на 1гб. И как то в 10 раз хуже вышло чем так.

Comment: Ну тогда хз :).

Comment: @tym32167 обновил - так имели ввиду ?

Comment: ну да, что то типа того

Comment: Вы их в оригинальном разрешении показываете? Или уменьшаете?

Comment: Попробуйте в ресурсы приложения загрузить, AppResources

Comment: Возможно, вам поможет это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/698310/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо за старания помочь. У меня оригинальные изображения в 1920 x 1080 и отображать их нужно в том же размере. Что то похожее на screensaver у Windows

Comment: Вам явно нужно использовать полноценное видео, а не имитировать его картинками

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
У меня оригинальные изображения в 1920 x 1080 и отображать их 
нужно в том же размере. Что то похожее на screensaver у Windows
```

такие изображения отрисовать быстро(на всех компьютерах) невозможно. Все упирается или в количество оперативки(загрузить все обьекты) или в быстроту работы винчестера(считать каждую картинку на НЕдефрагментированном диске будет довольно медленная задача, но с ССД выйдет быстренько)

_

*Можно пойти **неправильным** путем:*

Сделать FIFO-list (в шарпе это [Queue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.queue?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)) и при помощи его сделать буфер картинок, и картинки подгружать на 10-15 штук относительно того что сейчас используется.
Кароче, буферизация изображений в нужном количестве размером(подбирается опытным путем оптимальный из соображений занятая оперативка/быстрота работы). А так же не забываем диспоузить изображения что б оперативу освобждать!

Внутри FIFO сохранять, скажем, инстансы структуры:
Index
Image

Так же иметь Array путей. Индекс аррея будет равнятся индексу элемента FIFO. Но имеет в себе полный список путей изображений что бы понятно было с какого пути нужно будет грузить следующую картинку. Собственно, если индекс превышает количество ячеек - нужно начинать с первой.

Этот буфер в отдельном потоке подгружает нужное количество изображений, скажем, до 15 элементов начиная с занаддного индекса (картинка которая сейчас отрисовывается).

Заданный индекс меняется в то время, как отрисовывается теперешний твой кадр.

*Можно пойти **ВОЗМОЖНО правильным** путем (GIF):*

Смонтировать большую гифку и подгружать ее. Я не уверен сработает ли этот путь т.к. не знаю как гифки сохраняются в оперативке. Вполне возможно что как набор BMP кадров... Так что может и не сработать.

*А можно пойти **ПРАВИЛЬНЫМ** путем (Video):*

- Смонтировать видео, заменить Transparancy слой на хрома-кей, сжать его в x264 и потом проигрывать по кругу ВИДЕО обрабатывая хромакей. Это оптимальнее с точки зрения занимаемого места и проще в реализации(видео отобразить)
- Если же там полупрозрачные поверхности есть.... То смонтировать видео, экспортировать в видеоформат с поддержкой альфа-канала(RGBA), сжать его в x264. А потом реализовать поддержку обработки альфа-канала в твоей программе.

---

теперь на тему:

```
и память процесса переваливала за 4гб, хотя файлов там было на 1гб.
```

это потому, что ты подгружаешь в BMP (Bitmap) то есть в несжатую картинку. По-другому не выйдет.

Comment: Здорово! **Andrew** спасибо вам за такой ответ. Видимо неправильный путь, для меня будет самый правильный, так как мне нужно сохранять прозрачность, а с видео это сделать не смогу, так бы конечно запихал его в `MediaElement` и на этом бы задача была решена. Сейчас попробую разобраться с буфером картинок. Но если у Вас будет возможность более подробней об этом рассказать, было бы круто.

Comment: обновил ответ...

Comment: Спасибо, Queue освоил, но с потоками какая то беда, до сих пор не сделал, то что хотел.

Comment: я бы, все же, смотрел в стороноу видео с хромакеем. Это, как по мне, вариант более правильный. Там с потоками реально намучатся можно.

Comment: проблема с полупрозрачными элементами на хромакее

Comment: Тогда нужно смотреть в сторону отображения видео в цветовой схеме RGBA а не в RGB. Такие существуют. Например *.mov контейнер точно поддерживает альфаканал. Вот пример того как экспортить видео с альфа-каналом из афтер ефектс-а: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPZ3WfR5sx4

Comment: Как такие видео воспроизводить с прозрачностью ? Я пробовал с самого начала в этих вопросах разобраться, но ничего не нашёл и подумал что нужно пробовать с .png

Comment: На сколько я знаю МедиаЭлемент не поддерживает RGBA. Или нужно искать кастормный с поддержкожй RGBA или самому писать новый компонент с поддержкой RGBA(унаследовав от МедиаЭлемента)

Comment: Советую детальнее гуглить по запросу "C# play RGBA video". Там ты точно найдешь больше информации, чем то что я могу посоветовать. Т.к. мои познания весьма малы в этой сфере и все пишется, скорее, на основе догадок и логического мышления, чем на обьективном опыте :)