# Выполнить команду в другом потоке

Tags: c#, wpf

Как правильно под заполнить `qeImage` в другом потоке ?

Основной поток:

```
Queue<BitmapImage> qeImage = new Queue<BitmapImage>();

...

    private void dT_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imageKonteiner.Source = qeImage.Dequeue();
        Task.Run(() => qeImage.Enqueue(new BitmapImage(new Uri(arraySource[counter]))));
        counter++;
    }
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: "Вызывающий поток не может получить
>   доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является
>   другой поток."

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лучше этого не делать — у вас очередь не поддерживает многопоточный доступ

Comment: Ну а вообще — обернуть в `Task.Run`, например

Comment: `ConcurrentQueue`, `lock(qeImage){ ... }`

Comment: @АндрейNOP я пытаюсь сделать буферизацию как подсказали тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/893621/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-png, пробовал обернуть, получаю вот что https://i.imgur.com/P3k8teQ.png

Comment: А если вызвать `Freeze()` на `BitmapImage` (`qeImage.Dequeue().Freeze()`)? Ну и стоит добавить к вопросу метку используемого фреймворка

Comment: А вообще, лучше, наверное, в фоновом потоке только загружать данные, а конструировать объект и добавлять его в очередь в потоке GUI

Comment: @АндрейNOP имелось ввиду прям так https://i.imgur.com/EkZiwVe.png?

Comment: Эм, ну прям так не сработает, ага. Извлекайте, фризьте и устанавливайте. Либо фризьте перед добавлением в очередь

Comment: Скажу что тут очень помог бы `MVVM`!  Уважаемый ТС, если вы знаете что такое `MVVM`, умеете с ним работать, то попробйте сделать это именно с этой технологией.

Comment: @LLENN к сожалению пока не знаю, спасибо, возьму на вооружение.