# Оптимизация BitmapImage коллекции

Tags: c#, wpf

Разрабатываю проект, который должен читать из `.zip` архивов информацию (имя, описание, изображение). Для этой задачи я взял `DotNetZip`.

Сделал DTO класс:

```
class ENBModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage Image { get; set; }
}
```

Далее сделал некую коллекцию, в которую загружаю из всех найденных файлов данные, делаю это примерно так:

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    using (var zip = ZipFile.Read(file))
    {
        var enb = new ENBModel();
        using (var dataStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var dataZip = zip["PSSData.json"];
            dataZip.Extract(dataStream);
            var data = Encoding.Default.GetString(dataStream.ToArray());
            var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileDataModel>(data);
            enb.Name = json.Name;
        }

        var imageSource = new BitmapImage();
        using (MemoryStream imageSteam = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var imgZip = zip["Image.png"];
            imgZip.Extract(imageSteam);
            imageSource.BeginInit();
            imageSource.StreamSource = imageSteam;
            imageSource.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            imageSource.EndInit();
            enb.Image = imageSource;
        }

        Presets.Add(enb);
    }
}
```

В результате я имею все необходимое для вывода данных в View. Делаю это простым `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Presets}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

И после всех этих манипуляций я вижу, что у мое приложение кушает не 60мб RAM, а уже все 500. Я понимаю, да, идет хранение всех изображений в памяти, но как без этого быть?

Собственно, помогите это дело как то оптимизировать. Где бы я не находил про это информацию, везде совет "Поставьте `CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;`", но как видим стоит и результата ноль. Пробовал другие варианты, так вовсе получаю серые изображения.

Comment: Не по сути вопроса, но DTO не должен содержать сложные классы вроде BitmapImage, иначе это не DTO

Comment: Теперь по сути вопроса: не до конца понятно, что именно вам не нравится? Сколько весят картинки в извлеченном состоянии? Как вы их выводите, в 100% масштабе?

Comment: Это видели: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/698310/218063 ?

Comment: @АндрейNOP На экране выводится миниатюра, которая имеет размер 140х140, при наведении мыши выводится ToolTip с изображением, ограниченным до 1000х1000. Вес изображений в районе 1мб. Ну а не нравится то, что так много кушает памяти. Я не думаю, что тут проблема в View части, ибо если уберу ее полностью, то память будет также забита. Дело именно в том, что я считываю из архивов все картинки и забиваю ими коллекцию, как быть иначе не пойму...

Comment: Т.е вы хотите держать все картинки в памяти, но чтобы они ничего там не занимали?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Не обязательно держать их в памяти (я это наоборот пытаюсь избежать), может можно как то "выдирать" из архива по требованию или еще что. Главное что бы файл не распаковывался, был в архиве и сам архив был "свободен", для дальнейших манипуляций с ним. Можно конечно выгружать картинку из архива во временную директорию и от туда читать, но как то это странно...

Comment: Смотрите. Если я все понимаю правильно, то Вы в начале работы приложения загружаете в память zip-архив с картинками, который весит, видимо, немало. После этого Вы туда же, в память, загружаете сами картинки, да, загрузить zip-архив впамять -- мало. Картинки, судя по всему опять же не самые маленькие. В такой ситуации 500 МБ -- совершенно нормально. Вам стоит подумать о распаковке архива в папку приложения, если файлы не должны оставаться на диске, поместите их во временную папку, после этого, видимо, подгружать картинки по требованию. Но повторюсь, в текущей ситации 500 МБ -- это норма.

Comment: @SerafimProzorov Картинок примерно 30 штук, весом до 1 мб и того имеем ну грубо говоря 30мб. Архивы (их 30 штук), весят до двух мб, но не суть - они после того, как из них достается картинка, сразу закрываются и выгружаются из памяти. Также я не говорю, что это не норма/норма, я лишь спрашиваю "Как можно это грамотно оптимизировать `Без распаковки`".

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, я понял Ваш вопрос, просто немного рассуждаю и уточняю подробности. Без распаковки, я честно говоря, способов очень сильно оптимизировать я не вижу, архив ведь на самом деле не выгружается из памяти при вызове Dispose, освобождается лишь файловый дескриптор. Но в Вашем случае можно во-первых делать создание картинок по требованию, а во-вторых, посмотрите в сторону System.Buffers, тогда ненужные картинки (которые не видно), можно диспозить, а память возвращать в пул. Плюс, задумайтесь, действительно ли потребление памяти -- проблема для Вас?